# qTips do not appear on content type create form

Tags: forms, tooltips

I have installed [qTip (Stylish jQuery Tooltips)](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip) module `v7.x-2.0-rc3`, but I cant get it to work on a content type create form.

The steps I've followed are the following:

1. Install and enable qTip module along with Fields sub-module.
2. Create a new qTip instance with the default and simplest options.
3. Go to my content type and manage a Long text field with a text-area widget.
4. Enable the qTip Settings for it. Set it to Custom Text and fill in a sample text. Select my previously created qTip instance.
5. Press Save and clear all caches.

However when I go to the form (Content -> Add Content -> My_content_type) the qTips are nowhere to be seen. I've tried to hover over the label and the text editor. Nothing shows up.

On the other hand when I preview my instance the qTip appears normally:

[image: Instance preview]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no solution why this was happening, so I had to switch to [Form Tips](https://www.drupal.org/project/formtips) which worked flawlessly along with some custom CSS theming.